# Read Configuration Settings of Web.config in ASP.Net project using Javascript File

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to read Web.Config settings through javascript file. 
I have below reference link which suggest the same but works ONLY when we add the code in .aspx file and not when put into .JS file.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77917/Read-Configuration-Settings-of-Web-config-using-Ja

Is it possible to do that with code in .js file?

Comment: IIS will never allow the browser to directly request the `web.config` file.  Your only option is to stream the file via an `.aspx` page (or similar), but I wouldn't recommend it as it could potentially be a security issue

Comment: ^^ What freefaller said. You'd have to execute the javascript on the server, it would never work from the client. What are you trying to do exactly, if there's setting you need on the client side there's a multitude of different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

No, and you shouldn't want to (you can by changing the IIS ISAPI file handler, but NO!). The `web.config` file is a file that needs to be secured heavily, since it can contain usernames and passwords to databases and other resources. **The `web.config` should not be exposed to the outside world!**

That said, you might opt to create an `ashx` or `aspx` that reads a specific part of the `web.config` and exposes that to the page, but that is as far as I would go.

Answer (score 2):

IIS will never allow the browser to directly request the `web.config` file... so the simple answer is "No, you can't do that with javascript".

Your only option is to stream the file via an `.aspx` page (or similar), but I wouldn't recommend it as it could potentially (almost certainly) be a security issue.

*Edit:* As Patrick says in his answer above, if you need to expose specific parts, then that would be better - but don't expose the entire file.